Too many "Authorized committer" errors after upgrading to Pyspark==3.5.1
The problem
I have recently upgraded my apps to run on Spark3.5.1+YARN3.3.6, and observing frequent failures saying "Authorized committer". The apps run PySpark and I observe the error always happens in the output stage (while writing to S3).
Has anyone had a similar experience after upgrading to the recent version of Spark? I am suspecting it is related to this change but not entirely sure.
The full stack trace looks like:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Authorized committer (attemptNumber=0, stage=0, partition=11)
failed; but task commit success, data duplication may happen.
reason=ExecutorLostFailure(2,false,Some(Container container_1715218448129_414335_01_000005
on host: my-yarn-nm-server-1.com was preempted.))

What I tried out?
I enabled the magic committer in hopes that it is more reliable and fast, but I still see this failure (although the number of failures seem significantly reduced). Any leads to solve this would be highly appreciated.

had same issue with AWS EMR
check this
https://repost.aws/questions/QUmVnZdR3KQ-60ugXxXLBPIg/emrfs-write-errors
adding classification cluster solved this issue for me
{
   "Classification": "core-site",
   "Properties": {
      "fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.complete": "0.99"
   }
}


Interesting. Thank you so much.
Unfortunately, I think that config is specific to EMR (I am self-managing my Spark apps on Yarn). I couldn't find that config in the Hadoop doc, so I am guessing it won't work for me. :(
But thanks for sharing your answer though. I'll try to look at the other configs in that Hadoop doc and probably something works out for me.

This is actually a regression in spark; I've only just encountered recently..it is overreacting to what it perceives as a failure when aborting speculative tasks. Try turning off speculative execution (sorry, I forget the option...look at the apache spark docs)

Thanks! Based on this doc it seems that speculation is disabled by default. Since I haven't enabled speculation for any of my jobs, I believe that's not the issue here. :/ But, thanks again - appreciate your reply.
